# How could I solve the "teminted due to memory error" issue in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, instruments

I am a new IOS app developer and my app was developed for my company crashed due to a memory issue. During my investigation of the Xcode instruments, I discovered that when the "All Heap and Anonymous VM" reaches certain bits, it will crash. Then, I looked at the Xcode instrument in detail and realised that the app terminated when the **"All Heap and Anonymous VM"** reached **2.53 Gib total bytes**, **"All Anonymous VM"** reached **2.28 Gib total bytes**, and **"VM:ImageIO_PNG_Data"** reached **1.80 Gib total bytes**.
I also found out that when I clicked the Image button (I used AsyncImage to code the Image Button and the Images in the Image Button are from the API. I will list down my AsymcImage Code below.), the Anonymous VM's persistent and the total bytes surge exponentially. Apart from that, other interfaces do not contribute to the increase in Anonymous VM and other memory figures. Hence, I guess the problem is because of these image buttons. I am trying to figure out the solution to debug and optimise.

Here is the warning message and my picture for tracking memory:

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUOxI.png)

[Xcode Instrucment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad7DC.png)

Here is the interface:

[Interface: Image Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8GDF.png)

Here is my AsyncImage Code:

```
ForEach(userVM.user_data,id:\.self){ data in
    ForEach(userVM.getAllBusinessSegFor(index: data.client, com: data.businessSegments)) { segment in
        
        NavigationLink(destination:
                        CompanyList(
                            //title:item.name,
                            segment:segment,
                            companyParse: data.companies,
                            company:userVM
                        )){
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxx.com\(segment.img)" )){
                                phase in
                                switch phase{
                                case .empty:
                                    ProgressView()
                                case .success(let returedImage):
                                    returedImage
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .frame(width:314.38,height: 100)
                                    
                                    
                                case .failure:
                                    Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                default:
                                    Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                }
                            }
                        }
    }
}
```

I am not so sure what all these parameters mean and would like to know what are the ways to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: It looks like your app runs out of memory. How many images does the app display? How big (in pixels) are they on average?

Comment: I have added the interface for your reference as well.

Comment: @Codo There are 6 image buttons in my app. Each image originally has 6891 × 2748 pixels on the website (these images were stored in the form of URL and presented in API format). Then, I resized them into 314*100 pixels in the swift code after I parsed images from API and added the navigation button inside. I checked with the memory diagram in Xcode and the diagram tells me when I display these array of images, the memory will increase like crazy.

Comment: From the code it looks as if the images are scaled when they are rendered on the screen. In memory, they will still have the original size. This amounts to 6 x 6891 x 2748 x 4 = 455MB. That at least partially explains the huge memory demand.

Comment: I wonder if this is caused by the double ForEach loops and that you are downloading much more than 6 images. A simple test to see if this is the case could be to comment out the NavigationLink and replacing this with a Text that contains values from both the inner and the outer loop, something like `Text(\(data.client) \(segment.img))` and see how many rows of text you get.

Comment: Speak to your designer and ask them to make correctly sized images for your app available. Don't forget iPhone screens have a scale factor of up to 3x, so you'll need images 942x300 pixels

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hi, I used your method and see 6 links on the interface. Hence, it should fetch images from the API. I guess the problem is probably from the image size.

Comment: @Codo Could I ask why you times 4 when you calculate the image size? I thought in RGB format should times 3. Just want to know it depth.

Comment: It's not about RGB but the number of bits per pixel, if the images are jpeg for example you have 8 bit per pixel but then there is also the level of compression used when storing the image so it's not as simple as calculating the file size from the dimensions and the bit depth.

Comment: The decompressed image is held in memory such that it can quickly be rendered to the screen. Usually, this is 4 bytes per pixel because it better aligns with memory access. If the image has transparency, 4 bytes is needed anyway. But it is also possible that the graphics hardware of your particular device also support 3 bytes per pixel.